# Python 2.7.11 Dictionary Assignment (very simple)

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I need to create a code where students names and scores are stored in a dictionary in Python 2.7.11. I need to calculate the average score of each student and print it out. Here is what I have so far:

```
dict_grade= {'Alice':[68,70,90], 'Chris':[95,90,87], 'Cindy':[89,80,75], 'Adam':[75,70,69], 'Richard':[81,80,93], 'Ryan':[51,62,70], 'Edward':[88,90,94], 'Larry':[93,95,97], 'Seth':[67,70,80]}
average_grade= {name:averageScore}
def avg(dict_grade):
    return sum(dict_grade)/float(len(dict_grade))
for k, v in dict_grade.values():
     print 'Name: ', k, 'and the average score is: ', v
```

Any help will be so greatly appreciated! I know this is very simple stuff. Thanks:)

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
dict_grade= {'Alice':[68,70,90], 'Chris':[95,90,87], 'Cindy':[89,80,75], 'Adam':[75,70,69], 'Richard':[81,80,93], 'Ryan':[51,62,70], 'Edward':[88,90,94], 'Larry':[93,95,97], 'Seth':[67,70,80]}
def get_avg(record):
    return sum(record)/ float(len(record))
for k, v in dict_grade.items():
     avg_score =  get_avg(v)
     print 'Name: ', k, 'and the average score is: ', avg_score
```

Comment: @SAgardy : here way to say thanks is upvote and accept answer.